# Multiplying Two Dictionaries Together, Then Dividing By Sum of One Dictionary Key Value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am attempting to calculate the average value of a property over its domain for each time step. The formula I have been given to do this is:

(average value * area) / (sum of the areas)

My average value dictionary looks like this:

```
{1: [[15.454]],
 2: [[14.376598, 14.376598, 14.376598, 14.376598]],
 6: [[14.090124,
   14.090124,
   14.090124,
   14.090124,
   14.090124,
   14.090124,
   14.090124,
   14.090124]],
 7: [[10.425607,
   10.425607,
   10.425607,
   10.425607,
   10.425607,
   10.425607,
   10.425607,
   10.425607]],
 8: [[10.72365,
   10.72365,
   10.72365,
   10.72365,
   10.72365,
   10.72365,
   10.72365,
   10.72365]],
 9: [[10.18306,
   10.18306,
   14.019559,
   12.356618,
   12.356618,
   14.019559,
   10.18306,
   12.356618,
   12.356618,
   10.18306,
   10.18306,
   12.356618,
   12.356618,
   10.18306,
   14.019559,
   14.019559,
   12.356618,
   12.356618,
   10.18306,
   10.18306]],
 10: [[10.40247,
   10.40247,
   13.91327,
   13.91327,
   12.423714,
   12.423714,
   10.40247,
   13.91327,
   12.423714,
   12.423714,
   13.91327,
   10.40247,
   10.40247,
   13.91327,
   12.423714,
   12.423714,
   13.91327,
   10.40247,
   12.423714,
   12.423714,
   13.91327,
   13.91327,
   10.40247,
   10.40247]],
 11: [[13.399506,
   13.399506,
   13.799309,
   16.5947,
   16.5947,
   13.399506,
   13.399506,
   13.799309,
   13.799308,
   13.399506,
   13.399506,
   16.5947,
   16.5947,
   13.799308,
   13.399506,
   13.399506]],
 12: [[12.80158, 15.493244, 12.80158],
  [12.80158, 15.493244, 12.80158],
  [12.80158,
   12.80158,
   15.493244,
   15.493244,
   14.5616,
   14.5616,
   12.80158,
   12.80158,
   11.723698,
   11.723698,
   11.723698,
   11.723698,
   14.5616,
   14.5616,
   14.5616,
   14.5616,
   11.723698,
   11.723698,
   11.723698,
   11.723698,
   12.80158,
   12.80158,
   14.5616,
   14.5616,
   15.493244,
   15.493244,
   12.80158,
   12.80158],
  [12.80158, 15.493244, 12.80158],
  [12.80158, 15.493244, 12.80158]],
 13: [[16.340405, 12.286473, 12.286473],
  [16.340405, 12.286473, 12.286473],
  [10.751218],
  [10.751218],
  [10.751218],
  [10.751218],
  [12.286473, 12.286473, 16.340405],
  [12.286473, 12.286473, 16.340405]],
 14: [[12.673684,
   12.673684,
   11.751637,
   11.751637,
   11.806986,
   11.806986,
   11.944106,
   11.944106,
   11.950957,
   11.950957,
   13.114357,
   13.114358,
   11.751637,
   11.751637,
   11.806986,
   11.806986,
   11.247714,
   11.247714,
   11.944106,
   11.944106,
   11.247714,
   11.247714,
   11.950957,
   11.950957,
   12.673684,
   12.673684,
   12.673684,
   12.673684,
   11.950957,
   11.950957,
   11.247714,
   11.247714,
   11.944106,
   11.944106,
   11.247714,
   11.247714,
   11.806986,
   11.806986,
   11.751637,
   13.114358,
   13.114358,
   11.751637,
   11.950957,
   11.950957,
   11.944106,
   11.944106,
   11.806986,
   11.806986,
   11.751637,
   11.751637,
   12.673684,
   12.673684]],
 15: [[15.5075245,
   15.5075245,
   11.033852,
   11.033852,
   10.801203,
   10.801203,
   11.7755785,
   11.7755785,
   10.250238,
   10.250238,
   11.033852,
   11.033852,
   10.801203,
   10.801203,
   10.250238,
   10.250238,
   11.7755785,
   11.7755785,
   15.5075245,
   15.5075245,
   15.5075245,
   15.5075245,
   11.7755785,
   11.7755785,
   10.250238,
   10.250238,
   10.801203,
   10.801203,
   11.033852,
   11.033852,
   10.250238,
   10.250238,
   11.7755785,
   11.7755785,
   10.801203,
   10.801203,
   11.033852,
   11.033852,
   15.5075245,
   15.5075245]],
 16: [[11.458242,
   11.458242,
   11.246982,
   11.246982,
   10.998469,
   13.084064,
   10.998469,
   16.075857,
   16.075857,
   11.178662,
   10.835763,
   10.835763,
   11.178662,
   10.242558,
   11.081483,
   11.966127,
   11.966127,
   10.9047575,
   11.377513,
   10.9047575],
  [10.998469,
   11.178662,
   11.246982,
   10.835763,
   16.075857,
   10.9047575,
   11.458242,
   11.966127,
   13.0840645,
   10.242558,
   11.081483,
   11.377513,
   11.458242,
   11.966127,
   16.075857,
   10.9047575,
   10.835763,
   11.246982,
   10.998469,
   11.178662],
  [11.178662,
   10.998469,
   11.246982,
   10.835763,
   10.9047575,
   16.075857,
   11.966127,
   11.458242,
   11.377513,
   11.081484,
   10.242558,
   13.0840645,
   11.966127,
   11.458242,
   10.9047575,
   16.075857,
   10.835763,
   11.246982,
   11.178662,
   10.998469],
  [10.9047575,
   11.377513,
   10.9047575,
   11.966127,
   11.081484,
   11.966127,
   10.242558,
   10.835763,
   10.835763,
   11.178662,
   11.178662,
   16.075857,
   16.075857,
   13.0840645,
   10.998469,
   10.998469,
   11.246982,
   11.246982,
   11.458242,
   11.458242]]}
```

And my areas dictionary looks like this:

```
{1: [[36]],
 2: [[9, 9, 9, 9]],
 6: [[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]],
 7: [[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]],
 8: [[18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18]],
 9: [[9, 9, 18, 9, 9, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9]],
 10: [[9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9]],
 11: [[9, 9, 36, 18, 18, 9, 9, 36, 36, 9, 9, 18, 18, 36, 9, 9]],
 12: [[9, 9, 9],
  [9, 9, 9],
  [9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   18,
   18,
   18,
   18,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   18,
   18,
   18,
   18,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9],
  [9, 9, 9],
  [9, 9, 9]],
 13: [[9, 18, 18],
  [9, 18, 18],
  [54],
  [54],
  [54],
  [54],
  [18, 18, 9],
  [18, 18, 9]],
 14: [[9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   27,
   27,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   18,
   18,
   9,
   9,
   18,
   18,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   18,
   18,
   9,
   9,
   18,
   18,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   27,
   27,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9]],
 15: [[9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   18,
   18,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   18,
   18,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   18,
   18,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   18,
   18,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9,
   9]],
 16: [[9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 36, 9, 9, 9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 18, 36, 9, 9, 9, 18, 9],
  [9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9, 36, 18, 36, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 9],
  [9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9, 18, 36, 18, 36, 9, 9, 9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 9],
  [9, 18, 9, 9, 36, 9, 18, 18, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9, 36, 9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 9]]}
```

So an example calculation would look like this for hour 2:

```
(14.376598 * 9)+(14.376598 * 9)+(14.376598 * 9)+(14.376598 * 9) / (9+9+9+9) =
(129.39 + 129.39 + 129.39 + 129.39) / 36 = 14.376
```

I would then append this value to a list.

My question is: how do I go about accessing the value in these dictionaries? The fact that the dictionaries are in a list of lists is what is confusing me, and I am having trouble accessing the data in my for loops.

Suggestions?

Thank you!

**EDIT:
I created a basic for loop to print out the values for each dictionary:

```
for (value, area) in zip(avg_out.items(), area_out.items()):
    print(value, area)
```

This output the following:

```
(1, [[15.454]]) (1, [[36]])
(2, [[14.376598, 14.376598, 14.376598, 14.376598]]) (2, [[9, 9, 9, 9]])
(6, [[14.090124, 14.090124, 14.090124, 14.090124, 14.090124, 14.090124, 14.090124, 14.090124]]) (6, [[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]])
(7, [[10.425607, 10.425607, 10.425607, 10.425607, 10.425607, 10.425607, 10.425607, 10.425607]]) (7, [[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]])
(8, [[10.72365, 10.72365, 10.72365, 10.72365, 10.72365, 10.72365, 10.72365, 10.72365]]) (8, [[18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18]])
(9, [[10.18306, 10.18306, 14.019559, 12.356618, 12.356618, 14.019559, 10.18306, 12.356618, 12.356618, 10.18306, 10.18306, 12.356618, 12.356618, 10.18306, 14.019559, 14.019559, 12.356618, 12.356618, 10.18306, 10.18306]]) (9, [[9, 9, 18, 9, 9, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9]])
(10, [[10.40247, 10.40247, 13.91327, 13.91327, 12.423714, 12.423714, 10.40247, 13.91327, 12.423714, 12.423714, 13.91327, 10.40247, 10.40247, 13.91327, 12.423714, 12.423714, 13.91327, 10.40247, 12.423714, 12.423714, 13.91327, 13.91327, 10.40247, 10.40247]]) (10, [[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]])
(11, [[13.399506, 13.399506, 13.799309, 16.5947, 16.5947, 13.399506, 13.399506, 13.799309, 13.799308, 13.399506, 13.399506, 16.5947, 16.5947, 13.799308, 13.399506, 13.399506]]) (11, [[9, 9, 36, 18, 18, 9, 9, 36, 36, 9, 9, 18, 18, 36, 9, 9]])
(12, [[12.80158, 15.493244, 12.80158], [12.80158, 15.493244, 12.80158], [12.80158, 12.80158, 15.493244, 15.493244, 14.5616, 14.5616, 12.80158, 12.80158, 11.723698, 11.723698, 11.723698, 11.723698, 14.5616, 14.5616, 14.5616, 14.5616, 11.723698, 11.723698, 11.723698, 11.723698, 12.80158, 12.80158, 14.5616, 14.5616, 15.493244, 15.493244, 12.80158, 12.80158], [12.80158, 15.493244, 12.80158], [12.80158, 15.493244, 12.80158]]) (12, [[9, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 18, 18, 18, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9, 18, 18, 18, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9]])
(13, [[16.340405, 12.286473, 12.286473], [16.340405, 12.286473, 12.286473], [10.751218], [10.751218], [10.751218], [10.751218], [12.286473, 12.286473, 16.340405], [12.286473, 12.286473, 16.340405]]) (13, [[9, 18, 18], [9, 18, 18], [54], [54], [54], [54], [18, 18, 9], [18, 18, 9]])
(14, [[12.673684, 12.673684, 11.751637, 11.751637, 11.806986, 11.806986, 11.944106, 11.944106, 11.950957, 11.950957, 13.114357, 13.114358, 11.751637, 11.751637, 11.806986, 11.806986, 11.247714, 11.247714, 11.944106, 11.944106, 11.247714, 11.247714, 11.950957, 11.950957, 12.673684, 12.673684, 12.673684, 12.673684, 11.950957, 11.950957, 11.247714, 11.247714, 11.944106, 11.944106, 11.247714, 11.247714, 11.806986, 11.806986, 11.751637, 13.114358, 13.114358, 11.751637, 11.950957, 11.950957, 11.944106, 11.944106, 11.806986, 11.806986, 11.751637, 11.751637, 12.673684, 12.673684]]) (14, [[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 27, 27, 9, 9, 9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 9, 9, 27, 27, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]])
(15, [[15.5075245, 15.5075245, 11.033852, 11.033852, 10.801203, 10.801203, 11.7755785, 11.7755785, 10.250238, 10.250238, 11.033852, 11.033852, 10.801203, 10.801203, 10.250238, 10.250238, 11.7755785, 11.7755785, 15.5075245, 15.5075245, 15.5075245, 15.5075245, 11.7755785, 11.7755785, 10.250238, 10.250238, 10.801203, 10.801203, 11.033852, 11.033852, 10.250238, 10.250238, 11.7755785, 11.7755785, 10.801203, 10.801203, 11.033852, 11.033852, 15.5075245, 15.5075245]]) (15, [[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]])
(16, [[11.458242, 11.458242, 11.246982, 11.246982, 10.998469, 13.084064, 10.998469, 16.075857, 16.075857, 11.178662, 10.835763, 10.835763, 11.178662, 10.242558, 11.081483, 11.966127, 11.966127, 10.9047575, 11.377513, 10.9047575], [10.998469, 11.178662, 11.246982, 10.835763, 16.075857, 10.9047575, 11.458242, 11.966127, 13.0840645, 10.242558, 11.081483, 11.377513, 11.458242, 11.966127, 16.075857, 10.9047575, 10.835763, 11.246982, 10.998469, 11.178662], [11.178662, 10.998469, 11.246982, 10.835763, 10.9047575, 16.075857, 11.966127, 11.458242, 11.377513, 11.081484, 10.242558, 13.0840645, 11.966127, 11.458242, 10.9047575, 16.075857, 10.835763, 11.246982, 11.178662, 10.998469], [10.9047575, 11.377513, 10.9047575, 11.966127, 11.081484, 11.966127, 10.242558, 10.835763, 10.835763, 11.178662, 11.178662, 16.075857, 16.075857, 13.0840645, 10.998469, 10.998469, 11.246982, 11.246982, 11.458242, 11.458242]]) (16, [[9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 36, 9, 9, 9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 18, 36, 9, 9, 9, 18, 9], [9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9, 36, 18, 36, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 9], [9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9, 18, 36, 18, 36, 9, 9, 9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 9], [9, 18, 9, 9, 36, 9, 18, 18, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9, 36, 9, 9, 18, 18, 9, 9]])
```

I'm still struggling to understand how to multiply the values together. Simply attempting the following:

```
for value, area in zip(avg_out.items(), area_out.items()):
        product = value * area
```

I get an TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type tuple.

Comment: Looks like a job for https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip Would it change the question if we got rid of everything except the '2' key? You might also want to consider useful variable names -- I can guess pretty easily, but I don't know what you mean by the "area" and the "value".

Comment: I have in fact used zip in my for loop. Ideally, this calculation would be applied for every dictionary key (the key represents the hour). The value refers to the average wind speed over a region, and the area refers to the area in sq. km that the average is calculated over.

Comment: Ah, so you don't know how to iterate over a dict? "for hour in measurements:" or "for hour, values in measurements.items():"

Comment: I edited my original question showing my progress. Still having some issues.

Comment: You should probably use numpy for this, just much easier and faster

Answer (score 0):

zip works on lists. You will have to iterate over the dictionary normally, then zip the lists you get from that.

So your trial code would change to this:

```
for key in avg_out:
    for value, area in zip(avg_out[key], area_out[key]):
        product = value[0] * area[0]
```

If you have a list in a list, like value = [[1, 2, 3]], you can take value[0] or just *value if you're passing it to a function (e.g. zip)

```
for key in avg_out:
    for value, area in zip(*avg_out[key], *area_out[key]):
        product = value * area
```

And you can just work your way up from there. Sometimes when you iterate you can just pass the output of the iterable to another iterable like sum. Here's my rough draft:

```
for hour in avg_out:
    try:
        averages = avg_out[hour]
        areas = area_out[hour]
    
        if len(averages) != len(areas):
            print (f'length mismatch at hour {hour}')
            continue
        
        numerator = sum(map(lambda pair : pair[0] * pair[1], zip(*averages, *areas)))
        denominator = sum(*areas)
        print(f'hour {hour}: final result: {numerator / denominator}')
    except:
        print(f'bad data at hour {hour}')
```

Here we notice that the data has additional lists inside it. That's not really described in the question, but they appear to have the same structure. I can flatten it out with itertools.chain.from_iterable

```
for hour in avg_out:
    try:
        averages = itertools.chain.from_iterable(avg_out[hour])
        areas = itertools.chain.from_iterable(area_out[hour])
        
        numerator = 0
        denominator = 0
        for value, area in zip(averages, areas):
            product = value * area
            numerator += product
            denominator += area

        assert denominator > 0
        print(f'hour {hour}: final result: {numerator / denominator}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'bad data at hour {hour}', e)
```

Comment: If you're iterating over two dicts at the same time, you can take a union or intersection of their keys. You can iteratate over .items() to avoid having to recompute one of the hashes. I once saw an attempt to avoid recomputing the other hash, but that got pretty advanced, and would be silly here.

Comment: This worked very well except for hours 12, 13, and 16 where the exception was raised. Looking at these times it appears that they have blocks of lists like [[x, y, z], [a, b, c]] instead of [[x, y, z, a, b, c]] like the other times have. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I followed the formulate you gave in the question. I have no idea how to fix that so I just let it go to exception, because it's clearly outside the scope of the question. Although if it was supposed to be the later you could just pass all the areas through https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable

Comment: By passing all the areas through the chain.from_iterator(), do you mean wrapping the avg_out[hour] and area_out[hour] in that function? If so, that yields bad data for all hours.

Comment: It's a way to make [[x, y, z], [a, b, c]] look like (x, y, z, a, b, c). In this case, the avg_out has the same structure, so you'd have to do the same with the avg_out.

Comment: I understand what the chain.from_iterable() is doing; that makes sense to me, and I understand that both avg_out and area_out have the same structure and thus would need the same function applied to them. What I'm struggling with is finding where in the code the `chain.from_iterable(avg_out)` and `chain.from_iterable(area_out)` need to be applied. Anywhere I try to apply it yields the exception being thrown.

Comment: I posted the working code with that change.

Comment: If you're still getting an error, remove the try/catch and post the full exception chain.